# Conditional Regular Expression in java

Tags: java, regex

I have to develop a program that validates input from the user. String format is:

```
ebill (ao|aio|block) imran@example.com(any email address)
```

Now i'm looking for a solution with the following conditions:

- `ebill ao`  or `ebill aio` checks for third argument which is an email address.
- but if i got `ebill block` then my regular expression wouldn't check for email address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it this way:

```
ebill (((ao|aio) imran@imran.com)|block)
```

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is don't. Parse the list of arguments by splitting your string on spaces, and act upon each one as needed.

Comment: I disagree with you. Regular expression engine is very optimized and fast. Splitting string to chunks by spaces is not more effective than running precompiled regular expression against this string. Moreover String.split() uses regular expressions anyway.